# How translate MIPS I-format to binary?

Tags: mips

I don't know how to translating mips I-format instruction to binary.

For example,

$t0 is base of an int array A[].

And the way to get value of A[1] is

```
lw $t0, 4($t0) // 4 means 4bytes
```

35(6bits) | 8(5bits) | 8(5bits) |  4(16bits)

10011  / 00101 / 01000 /  0000 0000 0000 0100

Is it correct?

and

```
bne $t0, $s0, Exit          <- 80000
// other instruction1       <- 80004
// other instruction2       <- 80008
Exit:                       <- 80012
```

5(6bits) | 8(5bits) | 16(5bits) |  2(16bits)

00101  / 01000 / 10000 /  0000 0000 0000 0010

Pointer counter points instruction1(80004).
And address is byte address.
Is correct?

I know address in BNE is instruction distance between Program Counter.
I am confused why address in BNE is 2, not 8.

Answer (score 0):

> lw $t0, 4($t0) // 4 means 4bytes

> 35(6bits) | 8(5bits) | 8(5bits) | 4(16bits)

Yes

> 10011 / 00101 / 01000 / 0000 0000 0000 0100

No

100011 / 01000 / 01000 / 0000 0000 0000 0100

---

> bne $t0, $s0, Exit          <- 80000

> 5(6bits) | 8(5bits) | 16(5bits) | 2(16bits)

Yes

> 00101 / 01000 / 10000 / 0000 0000 0000 0010

Close

000101 / 01000 / 10000 / 0000 0000 0000 0010

(Make sure there's actually 6 digits in your 6-bit fields.)

With MIPS, all instructions are 32 bits wide, or 4 bytes long, and each instruction starts at an even 4 byte boundary (4 byte or word aligned, even multiple of 4).  Thus, for a branch, it is going from a 4 byte aligned address to another 4 byte aligned address.

A 4-byte aligned address has 2 low bits of zero.  The branch offset is the difference between 2 4-byte aligned addresses, and therefore such an offset also has 2 low bits that are zero.  There's no point in encoding those two zero bits in the instruction because it is known they're zeros.  So, the immediate encoded in the branch instruction is the branch offset divided by 4, which removes those zero bits, and also increases the branch offset's range by 2 bits.  (The assembler divides the offset by 4 to encode it and the hardware effectively multiplies the immediate by 4 in usage.)